# IOS - Adjust cell height based on content

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

im trying to build apps that have tableview cell similiar with twitter, there are text and images.
My problem is i want to insert the image above the text. While it can be text only.
So if there are no image, the text will be in position (0,0). And if there are images it will be (0,306) position.

Do i have to use programatically or using autolayout?

Appreciate for the answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use AutoLayout the use this code

You try to set the `UITableView` properties `estimatedHeight`.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     _messageField.delegate = self;
     _tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65.0;
     _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Other wise use this `UITableView` Delegate Method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 300; // your dynamic height...
}
```

Comment: do i have to set all the label and imageview using programatically by doing subiview or i can set using IB?thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do it programmatically use this delegate

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoLayout, just take an NSLayoutConstraint and bind it to the Top Space constraint of the label. Also you need to calculate the size of the label, to adjust cell height based on content.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //If image exists, set the value of the constraint to 306, else set it to 0
    constraintName.constant = 306;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    CGFloat labelHeight = [self findHeightForText:labelMe.text havingWidth:labelWidth andFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
    return labelHeight + paddingHeight;
}



//Method to calculate label height
- (CGFloat)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
    #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    #else
        size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    #endif
    }
    return size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //calculating the height according to the device height.
    return self.view.frame.size.height * (102.0 / 568.0);
}
```

Where 102.0 will be the current height according to the current design xib height 568.0. This will resize the cell according to the height.